# In azure devops: how can I inject my pipeline variables as appsettings when deploying a docker container to azure?

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, azure-devops, dockerfile

I'm having trouble setting my appsettings in a deployed docker container on azure.

My setup:

- I have a .NET core app
- My build pipeline builds a docker image and pushes it to my container registry on azure.
- My release pipeline pulls the image based on a tag and deploys it to an azure web app.

I need to deploy the image to multiple environments. Every environment has different appsettings. I defined the variables in my pipeline "variables tab":
[image]
And I need to send these to my azure so they can be used.
[image]

When I manually add them it works, but i want to extract them from my variables, so I only have to add them once. (see screenshot 1)
[image]
**Edit: The screenshot above works. But this is not what I'm looking for. As I'd have to edit the appsettings pipeline each time I add or remove a new appsetting. Also I believe that removing an appsetting here will just leave it on the deployed environment.**

I'm deploying an existing docker image, so i'm unable to edit the appsetting.json file. I also won't make different docker files for each environment.

Is there a way to achieve this? How can I extract / list the variables defined in my pipeline as docker variables or appsettings?

Comment: You shouldn't be baking configuration files into your containers. Have your application read app settings from environment variables and define the appropriate environment variables in your Azure app settings. Or use Azure App Configuration and manage these values within Azure.

Comment: What do you mean by "baking them into containers". My question is how can I set them during the release pipeline, so I don't need a appsetting-production.json appestting-acceptance.json etc for each environment.

Comment: Configuration values should be set in your Azure web app and loaded as environment variables, or your application can be configured to directly integrate with Azure Key Vault and Azure App Configuration, which provides an alternate method of loading and consuming application configuration.

Your continuous delivery pipeline is **not** the appropriate place to manage your application's configuration.

Comment: Then how do you suggest having appsettings for different environments?

Comment: You have multiple Azure Web Apps, right? Or staging slots? You set your app settings on the appropriate scope, or maintain multiple keyvaults or Azure App Configuration instances.

Comment: You are seriously the first one ever who tells me not to use release pipelines to manage app settings... But thanks, i'll take a look into it.

Comment: The reason is to avoid tightly coupling your application's configuration to your continuous delivery solution. Your application should be able to be built and deployed by **any** tool (Azure DevOps, Jenkins, TeamCity, GitHub Actions, or from a local machine for testing/debugging purposes).

Comment: You can define variables per stage in DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

You can define **pipeline variables** in your pipeline and have them attached to a specific **scope** (read stage) or the **release** scope (applied to all stages).

E.g. I have a variable defined as `EnvironmentConnectionString` which is defined in two scopes:

- Scope Test: "EnvironmentConnectionString = server=test-db; ...."
- Scope QA: "EnvironmentConnectionString = server=qa-db;..."
- Score Release: "logging_flag=enabled"

Then you can set this up in your "Application and Configuration Settings" like

```
- ConnectionString $(EnvironmentConnectionString)
- Logging $(logging_flag)
```

Note the $(variable name) syntax for using these variables

When the different stages of the pipeline run, they automatically pick up the values specific to the stage and apply to azure app settings.

Comment: Thank you, but is there away to automatically list all variables defined in the configuration settings? I don't want to edit that list on each environment (see my third screenshot)

Comment: There sure is if you’re happy to switch to yaml pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different variable groups for different stages. These Variable Groups should have **same** variables defined with different values.

For example: The `Dev` Variable Group and `Release` group both have variables `Port`, `RequestTimeout`... The `Port` in `Dev` is 4999 while the `Port` in `Release` could be 5000. We can link these groups to specific Stage scope, `Dev` variable group for `Dev` stage and `Release` group for `Release` stage.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Make sure all your stages have same settings like this, and then the variables with be replaced with correspondings values for different scopes.

**Update:**

Each stage in the pipeline is **independent**, they represent **different** environments. So we have to define the settings of stage or settings of the tasks within the stages one by one. We have to define the `appsettings` input one by one.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukbjs.png

Comment: Yes, but then I'd still have to define every setting and every variable in the "app settings" part right? My question was if there is a way to automatically extract ALL variables.

Comment: @Enrico Hope my update can resolve your puzzle. Feel free to let me know if I can help anything.

Comment: I'm afraid that i'm looking for a more automated solution. Listing all my variables one by one and passing them one by one to my container is not what i'm looking for. (see my screenshot with the black cross)

Comment: Sorry for my workaround can't work, but as i know in devops service there's no available feature to extract them from my variables directly... Maybe you can [add a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) about what you want in our user voice forum.